# exceCommand insertText inserting text twice when the text size is longer than specific character?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So I'm working on a chrome extension that inserts some texts in the twitter text field.

The following code works completely fine in chrome console,

```
document.getElementsByClassName("notranslate public-DraftEditor-content")[0].click();
document.execCommand('insertText', false, "A reply");
```

[image: through chrome console]

But the same code for some reasons repeats itself while using through chrome extension after a button click, the text element repeats twice.

[image: Through Extension]

Even after that only the first part of text is editable, and the second part is not for some reasons. This issue never happens while using it through console. But sometimes the extension also work fine.

After some debugging I realized that the function is getting called only once which is fine, but when the tweet it's replying to is longer than a few words, the extension inserting text twice for some reasons, and when the parent tweet is 3-4 words, it works just fine.

Example
https://twitter.com/BuckyDroid/status/1612838966105112576

So something going on when using the execCommand function through extension. Any suggestion how can I fix it?

Comment: execCommand is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand). Why not go all the way down to the most inner `span` and use [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) or [innerText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText)?

Comment: Direct DOM manipulation will be ignored by the site's internal scripts, but you can probably dispatch some events that will make the site recognize the new input.

Comment: Direct DOM does not work on twitter.